# How to do logging in servlets deployed to jboss 7.1

Tags: servlets, logging, jboss7.x

I am writing a simple web app with one servlet and my System.out.println statements (in my servlet) do not show up in the server.log file which for me is located at 
C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\log

So, I'm thinking that maybe I need to set up some kind of logging or something.  I am completely clueless on this.

I have tried to research log4j as an option but the more I research the more confused I get.

I need a step by step approach on this.  If anyone could please help I would be so thankful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest to start is IMHO using **[java.util.logging framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html)**. You don't need any special application dependency. It just works.

Example usage in a servlet:

```java
import java.util.logging.Logger;

private final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
  resp.setContentType("text/plain");
  final PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();
  writer.println("Logging message with SEVERE importance level");
  LOGGER.severe("Test log message with level SEVERE");
  writer.close();
}
```

Look on GitHub for a full **[example servlet](https://github.com/kwart/secured-webapp-template/blob/fb9e47c772eb3afb0c854246a70b12abd24e3f9e/src/main/java/org/jboss/test/LoggingTestServlet.java)**.

To enable **all log-levels** for your application, you can use **JBoss CLI** (`jboss-cli.sh` / `jboss-cli.bat`). Here is example, assuming your application is under `org.jboss.test` package:

```
connect
/subsystem=logging/console-handler=CONSOLE:write-attribute(name=level,value=ALL)
/subsystem=logging/logger=org.jboss.test:add(level=ALL)
quit
```

Comment: Thank you @kwart.  This helped me tremendously!